# In C#, how I can I wrap a string in brackets?

Tags: c#, string, overwrite

If you take for example the string

```
.Remove "S"
```

In C#, I would like to apply a function to the string to wrap the `"S"` part in brackets, resulting in the following string:

```
.Remove ("S")
```

I can't find the function, but I'm expecting to write something like the following:

```
(".Remove \"S\"").Overwrite("\"S\"", "(\"S\")");
```

Please can anyone help me?

Comment: Would you mind formatting your question? I have a hard time understanding, what is code and what isn't. (And I did not understand what your actual problem is)

Comment: Please show your sample input as compilable C# code and then when the output would be.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there.

This can be achieved programatically as follows:

```
string source = ".Remove \"S\"";

// Replace all occurrences of one char with another.

string replacement = source.Replace('\"S\"', '(\"S\")');
```

For more details refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/modify-string-contents

Note: Within the Visual Studio interface, there is also the ability to search and replace `(CTRL+H)`.